# comparing bytea to bytea in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am writing a function that will read data from large object and compare it to data supplied as arg. (I want to make sure I wrote it correctly, this is a post write sanity check)

I have worked out how to read the large object in chunks

```
   fd := lo_open(looid,x'40000'::int);
    loop
        buff := loread(fd,  1000);
        len := octet_length(buff);
        raise NOTICE 'buff %', len;
        if len = 0 then
           exit;
        end if;
    end loop;
    return 0;
```

but am stuck on the seemingly simple operation of comparing each chunk to the equivalent slice of my input bytea (say indata). I dont even know where to start and extensive ggoling revels no clues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`substring(string [from int] [for int])`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-binarystring.html).

The loop may look like this:

```
offst := 1;
loop
    buff := loread(fd,  1000);
    len := octet_length(buff);
    raise NOTICE 'buff %', len;
    if buff <> substring(indata from offst for 1000) then
        return false;
    end if;
    if len = 0 then
        return true;
    end if;
    offst := offst + len;
end loop;
```

Comment: and of course the len = 0 check needs to be before the compare or the substring needs to be for 'len' not 1000

Comment: No, it's ok. If you change this, you can overlook the case where `indata` is larger than the stored object. The value `for` may exceed the size of the bytea string in `substring()`.

Comment: actually the issue was when the data is < 1000. I changed the to `if sub(buff off len) <> sub(indata off len)`

Comment: I see, but the error is somewhere else - `offset` must start from 1, not 0(!). The answer corrected.